# SSRS Subscription - 2 different reports in one Excel file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two SSRS reports and I would like to have them subscribed in one Excel file attached to an email.

Is there any ways to do that or something like that?

Comment: Two report? or Dataset?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!. Currently they are two independent reports with a dataset for each. I'll be happy if I could make one report with two different dataset and export them as one Excel file with two sheets.

Comment: You can export it in one excel file with different sheets if you create your report with diff. dataset.

Comment: Thanks Jacky! I'll try it and provide the feedback later.

Comment: @Jacky I think I misunderstood something. I created two datasets and put two tablix  in one report. I subscribed it via email-attached Excel and found in it only one sheet with two datasets. Could you let me know how can I have it divided in two sheets?

Comment: Oh I see. you did not add a page break after your first tablix so that it did not divide into 2 sheets. What are you using to create your report? BIDS or Report Builder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137094/discussion-between-jacky-montevirgen-and-yobioo).

Comment: @Jacky Thank you so much for the advice via IM. Adding the  page break to the first tablix (page break after the tablix) resolved my issue.

Comment: Happy to hep you!